# Is there a way to do switch expression fallthrough with lambda-like syntax for default case?

Tags: java, switch-expression

What I'm trying to do is something like this, where a specific value & the default case can both map to a single value. I should clarify that the purpose of this is to be as explicit as possible. I understand that just using default would achieve the same functional result.

```java
return switch(value) {
    case "A" -> 1;
    case "B" -> 2;
    case "ALL"
    default -> -1;
};
```

Comment: according the [Java Language Specification 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) that is not possible (BTW that is a `switch expression` and not a `switch statement`)

Comment: Didn't think so, thanks

Comment: Knowing what things are called generally helps with looking up the relevant information.

Answer (score 3):

This was intended to be possible with [Pattern Matching for switch](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406) and even implemented in a preview phase.

So when you use `--enable-preview` with JDK 17 to JDK 19, the following works:

```java
return switch(value) {
    case "A" -> 1;
    case "B" -> 2;
    case "ALL", default -> -1;
};
```

Unfortunately, this support has been removed with JDK 20. With JDK 20’s preview and the release version of JDK 21, only `case null, default` is supported but mixing other case labels with `default` is not possible.

The change is documented in [JDK-8294946](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8294946). There seem to be no plans to revive this feature at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Combining default with a case is not possible and would be redundant (why the case then?), but combining cases with the lambda is possible:

```
return switch (value) {
    case "A", "B" -> 1;
    default -> -1;
};
```